# Connecting two laptops as each other external monitors

Tags: linux, windows, display, hdmi

In my working room I have to laptops, one with Windows and another with Ubuntu, and one extarnal screen. Depending on my needs i connect external screent to one of laptops via HDMI. Now I am in my family house and I don't have access to external screen and i would like to use screen of one laptop for another laptop. Once Ubuntu should be host, and once Windows. Is there easy and convienient way to do this?

Comment: The only way this can be done is if one has HDMI input functionality _(most laptops don't, as it generally requires a discrete GPU)_. If one of the laptops does have this functionality, there will be a function key _(e.g. `Fn`+`F9`)_ that switches between the HDMI input source and the OS while booted to the discrete GPU.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-an-old-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-Ubuntu